# Ejecutar un main en Robocode

Tags: java

quiero ejecutar una clase con un main en Robocode para que cree un campo de batalla personalizado y no consigo ejecutarlo. La clase en cuestión es la siguiente:

```
public class RouteFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Creamos un mapa con los datos especificados
            // Create the battlefield
            int numPixelFila= 800;
            int numPixelCol=600;
            int tamCelda = 50; //celdas de 50 x 50

................

            /* 
             * Crear y desarrollar la batalla con los robots antes definidos
             */
            BattleSpecification battleSpec =
                    new BattleSpecification(battlefield,
                            numberOfRounds,
                            inactivityTime,
                            gunCoolingRate,
                            sentryBorderSize,
                            hideEnemyNames,
                            existingRobots,
                            robotSetups);

            // Ejecutar la simulación el tiempo especificado
            engine.runBattle(battleSpec, true); 
            // Cerrar la simulación
            engine.close();
            // Asegurarse de que la MV de Java se cierra adecuadamente.
            System.exit(0);
        }
}
```

Utilizo el entorno Eclipse, y en Robocode tengo la referencia este proyecto. Al ejecutar esta clase abre la aplicación pero se queda en negro con el logo, es decir, como si se ejecutase solo, sin tener en cuenta este main.

Answer (score 1):

Te faltan las especifaciones sobre el motor de Robocode y los parámetros del campo de batalla:

```
    // Crear el RobocodeEngine desde una instalación en C:/Robocode
    RobocodeEngine engine =
            new RobocodeEngine(new java.io.File("C:/Robocode"));
    // Mostrar el simulador de Robocode
    engine.setVisible(true);


   //configuramos los parámetros del campo de batalla
    BattlefieldSpecification battlefield =
            new BattlefieldSpecification(numPixelFila, numPixelCol);

    int numberOfRounds = 5;
    long inactivityTime = 10000000;
    double gunCoolingRate = 1.0;
    int sentryBorderSize = 50;
    boolean hideEnemyNames = false;
```